# Tomcat not displaying page

Tags: java, spring, web, tomcat

I have upgraded some projects from Spring Boot 1.5.19 to 2.3.0, 1 of the projects gives a 404 error when I open the homepage.
Using the debugger I can see the code snippet below is returning early as the context object in the request is null.
The code snippet is from org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.

```
public final void invoke(Request request, Response response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    // Select the Context to be used for this Request
    Context context = request.getContext();
    if (context == null) {
        return;
    }
```

The other projects I have converted are displaying home pages correctly, the context in the request in these has a TomcatEmbeddedContext object.

Comment: Thanks, but I am already using server.servlet.context-path